# Has anyone connected more than 3 sensors to ROS? If so, how can we manage it? Is it advisable to use a usb splitter?

Tags: ros, multiple, sensor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to connect a stargazer sensor, a laser scanner and a kinect sensor to the ROS laptop.  The laptop has 3 usb ports and one is taken by the turtlebot (the robot platform), one by the kinect sensor and one by the laser scanner.  I wish to know whether it is good to use a usb splitter to connect the stargazer.  Any other suggestions on doing the same is appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/172621/has-anyone-connected-more-than-3-sensors-to-ros?--if-so,-how-can-we-manage-it?--is-it-advisable-to-use-a-usb-splitter?/) by [Aravinda](https://answers.ros.org/users/18763/aravinda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-06-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should be able to use a USB hub to connect more than three USB devices to your laptop, particularly if they don't require a lot of bandwidth.

Since one of your sensors is the Kinect, you'll have to pay very close attention to which USB bus each sensor is attached to, since the Kinect uses most of the USB2.0 bus bandwidth, and works best when it is on a bus by itself.

You can view the USB bus topology with `lsusb -t`.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-06-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5